# I have an array of objects as an input, using the fields in it, I have to form a dynamic query for salesforce

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft

Basically if I have "n" objects as input, then that should be used in the query to form "n" conditions.

Input

```
[
{
Id: "Id1",
System: "System1"
},
{
Id: "Id2",
System: "System2"
}
]
```

Output

```
Select Name FROM Account where (Id = "Id1" and System="System1") OR (Id = "Id2" and System="System2")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**WARNING: creating SQL queries from strings can be the cause of an [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerability. You are responsible on how to prevent that vulnerability**

Using reduce() you can convert each element of the array into a string to concatenate them all:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
"Select Name FROM Account where " ++ (payload reduce ((item, acc="") -> acc ++ (if(sizeOf(acc)>0) " OR " else "") ++ "(Id = \"" ++ item.Id ++"\" and System=\"" ++ item.System ++ "\")" ))
```

Comment: Is there a better way to do it then, to prevent SQL injections?